# Icollection.Remove not working

Tags: c#

```
public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
{
    get
    {
        List<ContactNumber> list = new List<ContactNumber>();

        if (Contact != null)
        {
            if (Contact.Qualifier1 != null || Contact.Number1 != null)
                list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier1, Number = Contact.Number1 });
            if (Contact.Qualifier2 != null || Contact.Number2 != null)
                list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier2, Number = Contact.Number2 });
            if (Contact.Qualifier3 != null || Contact.Number3 != null)
                list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier3, Number = Contact.Number3 });

        }
        return list;
    }
    set
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            ContactNumber cn = value.ElementAt(i);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    Contact.Qualifier1 = cn.Qualifier;
                    Contact.Number1 = cn.Number;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Contact.Qualifier2 = cn.Qualifier;
                    Contact.Number2 = cn.Number;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Contact.Qualifier3 = cn.Qualifier;
                    Contact.Number3 = cn.Number;
                    break;


                default:
                    // Should never reach here
                    //TODO: Handle ToManyContactNumbersException
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class ContactNumber
{
    public string Qualifier { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}



ContactNumber adj = this.ContactNumbers.ElementAt(1);
ContactNumber itemToRemove = this._billingProvider.ContactNumbers.SingleOrDefault(i => (i.Number == adj.Number) && (i.Qualifier == adj.Qualifier));
foreach (ContactNumber cn in this._billingProvider.ContactNumbers)
{
    if ((cn.Number == itemToRemove.Number) && (cn.Qualifier == itemToRemove.Qualifier))
        this.ContactNumbers.Remove(cn);
}
```

Why isn't the element being removed from the list. Even before Remove it has 3 items and the same after removing it

EDIT 1:

```
    public partial class BillingProvider
    {
     private List<ContactNumber> list = new List<ContactNumber>();
       public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
            {

                get
                {
                    return list;
                }
                set
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ContactNumber cn = value.ElementAt(i);
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                Contact.Qualifier1 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number1 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Contact.Qualifier2 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number2 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Contact.Qualifier3 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number3 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Contact.Qualifier4 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number4 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Contact.Qualifier5 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number5 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                Contact.Qualifier6 = cn.Qualifier;
                                Contact.Number6 = cn.Number;
                                break;
                            default:
                                // Should never reach here
                                //TODO: Handle ToManyContactNumbersException
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       public void InitializeContactNumbersList()
            {
                if (Contact != null)
                {

                    if (Contact.Qualifier1 != null || Contact.Number1 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier1, Number = Contact.Number1 });
                    if (Contact.Qualifier2 != null || Contact.Number2 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier2, Number = Contact.Number2 });
                    if (Contact.Qualifier3 != null || Contact.Number3 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier3, Number = Contact.Number3 });
                    if (Contact.Qualifier4 != null || Contact.Number4 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier4, Number = Contact.Number4 });
                    if (Contact.Qualifier5 != null || Contact.Number5 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier5, Number = Contact.Number5 });
                    if (Contact.Qualifier6 != null || Contact.Number6 != null)
                        list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier6, Number = Contact.Number6 });
                }
            }
    }

private void BillingProvider_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _billingProvider.InitializeContactNumbersList();
Bindignsource1.datasourece = _billingProvider.ContactNumbers
}
   private void menuDelete_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            ContactNumber adj = this._billingProvider.ContactNumbers.ElementAt(focussedRow);
            ContactNumber itemToRemove = this._billingProvider.ContactNumbers.SingleOrDefault(i => (i.Number == adj.Number) && (i.Qualifier == adj.Qualifier));
            this._billingProvider.ContactNumbers.Remove(itemToRemove);
           iscontrolDirty=true;
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getter you're re-creating the list every time someone asks for it.  When someone then goes and modifies the list it doesn't matter because when someone asks for the list again you're just creating a new one.

Instead you should be creating the collection once, and adding values to it in the constructor, rather than re-creating it in the getter.  The setter for the collection is also designed to set an *entirely new collection*, not to set a new value for some item in the collection.  You would use the collection's methods to do that.

Comment: Could you show me some sample code for the setter. I am getting the element(i) and assigning it

Comment: @user575219 The code getting the list and setting a value isn't flawed; the problem, as the answer describes, is that the getter for the property is *creating a new list*.  It shouldn't do that, it should just be returning a list that has already been created.  It should be created in your constructor.

Comment: See edit1. Added a new method which loads the list on Form_Load . But when an item from the list is removed, it removes it but the context does not track it. So wondering if it is a setter problem

Comment: @user575219 Your code isn't even using the setter.  You're just mutating the collection, rather than setting an entirely new collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you create a new list each time the property is accessed. Change your code to something similar to this:

1) Add a collection field to your class:

```
List<ContactNumber> list = new List<ContactNumber>();
```

2) Add initialization in the constructor:

```
if (Contact.Qualifier1 != null || Contact.Number1 != null)
    list.Add(new ContactNumber
        { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier1, Number = Contact.Number1 });
if (Contact.Qualifier2 != null || Contact.Number2 != null)
    list.Add(new ContactNumber
        { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier2, Number = Contact.Number2 });
if (Contact.Qualifier3 != null || Contact.Number3 != null)
    list.Add(new ContactNumber
        { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier3, Number = Contact.Number3 });
```

3) Change the getter to this:

```
public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
{
    get
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a default  constructor with no parameters which is generated by the EFModel. These additional properties are in a supplemental partial class.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
this.ContactNumbers.Remove(cn);
```

The item is removed from the list. But that doesn't matter, because you then throw away that modified list. Next time when you call

```
public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
{
    get
    {
        List<ContactNumber> list = new List<ContactNumber>();
        /// ....

        return list;
    }
```

you get a new list, a different one. Obviously, the remove from the previous list has no impact on this one.