# partial constructor to remove initialization from getter

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Class1
{
    public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            List<ContactNumber> list = new List<ContactNumber>();
            if (Contact != null)
            {
                if (Contact.Qualifier1 != null || Contact.Number1 != null)
                    list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier1, Number = Contact.Number1 });
                if (Contact.Qualifier2 != null || Contact.Number2 != null)
                    list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier2, Number = Contact.Number2 });
                if (Contact.Qualifier3 != null || Contact.Number3 != null)
                    list.Add(new ContactNumber { Qualifier = Contact.Qualifier3, Number = Contact.Number3 });
             }
             return list;
         }
         set
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
             {
                 ContactNumber cn = value.ElementAt(i);
                 switch (i)
                 {
                     case 0:
                         Contact.Qualifier1 = cn.Qualifier;
                         Contact.Number1 = cn.Number;
                         break;
                     case 1:
                         Contact.Qualifier2 = cn.Qualifier;
                         Contact.Number2 = cn.Number;
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         Contact.Qualifier3 = cn.Qualifier;
                         Contact.Number3 = cn.Number;
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         Contact.Qualifier4 = cn.Qualifier;
                         Contact.Number4 = cn.Number;
                         break;
                 }
```

```
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public partial class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        ////
    }
```

Can someone suggest to say to remove the initialization from the getter. 
Where can I initialize it? There is a constructor already defined. 
Is there like a partial constructor? Even using a partial constructore may not help. It should be partial Class1() in both classes and one of them is generated by default in EF 4.0

EDIT 2:

```
public virtual ObservableListSource<Adjustment> Adjustments { get; set; }
 public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource
        where T : class
    {
        private IBindingList _bindingList;

        bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } }

        IList IListSource.GetList()
        {
            return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList());
        }


    }

 public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
        {

            get
            {
                return list;
            }

        }
```

One needs COllectionchanged property implemented and one does not..?

Comment: Maybe you can change how EF generates the class? Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

Comment: Any other alternatives? We could change how EF generates the code. But this would affect a lot of other things.

Comment: Are there any `partial` methods you might be able to use?

Comment: Here's what I tried.. _class1.InitializeList(). In this method I am loading the list and then return the list on get accessor. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a reason you want to remove the code from there? Don't you like it there? Is there something special you want to achieve? Maybe you're asking the wrong question :-)

Comment: @Akku: It all started with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199385/icollection-remove-not-working. Was trying to remove a row from a Icolelction and the getter was the problem. So it removes it from the list but the context does not get updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if I understand your questions right, you're asking the wrong question. You have a set of Contacts in a list and you want to return a list of all contacts that match of of the contacts subproperties.

I wouldn't use a property for that. Just make a method like this:

```
public List<Contact> FilterContacts(Contact con)
{
    var copy = new List<Contact>();
    foreach (Contact cn in Contacts)
    {
        if (cn.number == con.number)
            copy.add(cn);
        else
            if (cn.name == con.name)
                copy.add(cn);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

I guess this is what you mean. Might be I'm completely wrong about this, but if you rephrase your question to what you actually try to do, it's easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I have a set of contacts loaded in the grid. I just want to add/delete a contact. I can delete it from the grid but it doesnt updated the datasource. this._billingproviders.ContactNumbers  is the datasource. this._billingproviders.contactNumbers.Remove(item) removes it from the list now. But the context doesn't track it.  The datasource is a ICollection. There is nothing different in the way I am loading it into the context. So I am wondering if it could be the setters?

Comment: Ah! You need to use an ObservableCollection<ContactThingy> and bind to that. This will fire an event to update the UI when to add or remove something to it. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okkk, Thanks, so this is how the class is declared:    public ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers
        {get.{return list} set{} }

Comment: I have another class ObservableListSource>Adjustment>, see edit 2: Grid takees ObservableListSource as the Datasource. Why is it that this grid tracks the change and the other contactNumbers DS doesn't.  Observablelistsource and the other is a ICollection?

Comment: Why are you telling me how the class is declared? Bind the grid to the ObservableCollection (do not use ICollection!), and put your ContactNumbers in that ObservableCollection. AFK.

Comment: ICollection doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which is an interface that classes need to implement so they can tell the UI that something has changed. Just don't use ICollection.